# PHP show certain <span> when PW or User is wrong

Tags: php, html

I want PHP to show a certain span when a wrong password or username is entered, otherwise it should be hidden. How can I get this to happen? I tried everything, but I am actually new to PHP and found this code on the internet.

here's my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rLF5N/)

and here is my code:

```
<?php
     if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
     session_start();

     $username = $_POST['username'];
     $passwort = $_POST['passwort'];

     $hostname = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
     $path = dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);

     // Benutzername und Passwort werden überprüft
     if ($username == 'admin' && $passwort == 'admin') {
        $_SESSION['angemeldet'] = true;

            // Weiterleitung zur geschützten Startseite
            if ($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] == 'HTTP/1.1') {
                if (php_sapi_name() == 'cgi') {
                    header('Status: 303 See Other');
                }
                else {
                    header('HTTP/1.1 303 See Other');
                }
            }

       header('next.php');
       exit;
       }           
      }
?>

<div class="contactForm" id="contactForm" style="width: 500px; 
    margin: auto; float: left;">    
<form name="myform" method="post" action="login.php">
<p class="form" style="width: 245px; height: 116px; margin-right: 10px;">
   <input class="field" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Name" />
   <input class="field" type="password" autofocus name="passwort" 
       placeholder="Passwort" />
   <button class="button" name="Submit" >Login</button><br>
   <span class="certainDiv" style="color:red;">This div should actually come 
       up when PW or User is wrong!</span>
</p>
</form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty easy fix, if you replace the

```
<span class="certainDiv" style="color:red;">This div should actually come up when PW or User is wrong!</span>
```

With

```
<?php
    if(isset($wrong)){
        echo '<span class="certainDiv" style="color:red;">This div should actually come up when PW or User is wrong!</span>';
    }
?>
```

And then under the

```
exit;
```

On line 28, replace the rest of the code in the PHP tags with

```
} else {
    $wrong = true;
}
```

It should work fine with these changes :)

Comment: sounds good, but it doens't work! I just uploaded it and typed in a wrong user and password and clicked on Login, then the page refreshes and I am not redirected, but no "certainDiv" appears..

Comment: Seems like extra code considering that if the user/pass is correct it won't show the form in the first place. See `header('next.php');
       exit;`

Answer (score 0):

One option is to simply surround it with an 'if'

```
<?php if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'): ?>
    <span class="certainDiv" style="color:red;">This div should actually come up when PW or User is wrong!</span> 
<?php endif; ?>
```

Also, you might want to try http://phpfiddle.org/ next time for PHP questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a variable when credentials are incorrect and use it in the html part as below.

```
<?php
 if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
 session_start();

 $username = $_POST['username'];
 $passwort = $_POST['passwort'];

 $hostname = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
 $path = dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);

 // Benutzername und Passwort werden überprüft
 if ($username == 'admin' && $passwort == 'admin') {
    $_SESSION['angemeldet'] = true;

        // Weiterleitung zur geschützten Startseite
        if ($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] == 'HTTP/1.1') {
            if (php_sapi_name() == 'cgi') {
                header('Status: 303 See Other');
            }
            else {
                header('HTTP/1.1 303 See Other');
            }
        }

      header('next.php');
      exit;
   } else {
      //means the username or password is incorrect at this point
      $invalidLogin = true;
   }

  }
?>


<div class="contactForm" id="contactForm" style="width: 500px; margin: auto; float: left;">    
<form name="myform" method="post" action="login.php">
<p class="form" style="width: 245px; height: 116px; margin-right: 10px;">
<input class="field" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Name" />
<input class="field" type="password" autofocus name="passwort" placeholder="Passwort" />
<button class="button" name="Submit" >Login</button><br>


<?php
   if(isset($invalidLogin) && ($invalidLogin)){
      echo '<span class="certainDiv" style="color:red;">This div should actually come up when PW or User is wrong!</span>';
   }
?>

</p>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: First bracket needed closing for the if clause. I've edited the code now.